# How do I fix this sinking walkway?

Tags: repair, cement, backyard, walkway, sidewalk

My cement walkway is slowly sinking as the dirt has given way with erosion. Is there a DIY friendly way to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

My one thought was using a carjack to lift it up then filling with dirt and slowly easing the carjack out. Idk.

Comment: You might be able to mud jack that up, but it may not last.  Solving the erosion problem will make it last longer.

Answer (score 1):

Typical problem of incorrect installation.

Laying concrete directly over dirt will lead to erosion issues.

What is missing is a layer of crushed stone about 4 inches thick, under the concrete.

That is how you fix it

Comment: And yes, that means tip it up and redo it properly.

Comment: No surprise as previous owners were abject morons. So by “tip up” does my plan to jack it up with a car jack sound ok? Or do I need a forklift?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use a car jack.  It would be easier to use a trolley jack rather than a bottle jack.

- Ensure that it is not snagging against the decking beam/joist  or you will damage it or the concrete.
- While jacked up, ensure that you don't put any limbs under the concrete (in case it slips).

Answer (score 0):

There is also a spray foam product that you can use to fill the void that will expand like Great Stuff foam and will lift up the slab. I would put down a 4" gravel bed also as was suggested previously by another poster.

Comment: It would be hard to find this product unless you specify a name (as an example) or a better description for the category of foam.